# How to generate multiple builds using Maven for one project

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I've following scenario:

1. ProjectA have two dependencies depA and dep2
2. I want to create two builds one with both dependencies and another one just have one dependency.

Now, my question is:

1. How can I achieve custom builds?
2. Can I create simply two POM files? If yes, then how should I be building projects using specific POM?

Comment: Which is the purpose of including the dependency in one project and not in the other one? Is it already provided in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could create multiple output packages.  One is to use the maven assembly plugin to create multiple archives.  The other is to create a multi-module project and give each artifact it's own pom.xml.  I would recommend the latter case as it embeds less assembly logic in your pom.  In this case I would create at least three modules... one for the project artifact with no packaged dependencies and two others for that artifact plus the various dependency items.

Comment: I think having a single output per module is the maven way. Especially if there are different dependencies for the outputs, I would also strongly recommend the multi-module-way.